# JQuery Anchor Link Scrolling to Wrong Position (Certain Devices Only)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get my page to scroll to an anchor when a link is clicked, taking into account the size of the header which changes based on viewport width. This works in the desktop version of Chrome however in the mobile version the header height isn't taken into account and the page scrolls to the top of the anchor which is hidden under the header.

This is my code adapted from CSS Tricks:

```
 var headerHeight = document.getElementById('header').clientHeight;

                      // Select all links with hashes
                      $('a[href*="#"]')
                        // Remove links that don't actually link to anything
                        .not('[href="#"]')
                        .not('[href="#0"]')
                        .click(function(event) {
                          // On-page links
                          if (
                            location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '')
                            &&
                            location.hostname == this.hostname
                          ) {
                            // Figure out element to scroll to
                            var target = $(this.hash);
                            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
                            // Does a scroll target exist?
                            if (target.length) {
                              // Only prevent default if animation is actually gonna happen
                              event.preventDefault();
                              $('html, body').animate({
                                scrollTop: target.offset().top-headerHeight
                              }, 1000, function() {
                                // Callback after animation
                                // Must change focus!
                                var $target = $(target);
                                $target.focus();
                                if ($target.is(":focus")) { // Checking if the target was focused
                                  return false;
                                } else {
                                  $target.attr('tabindex','-1'); // Adding tabindex for elements not focusable
                                  $target.focus(); // Set focus again
                                };
                              });
                            }
                          }
                      });
```

The page should scroll with an offset equal to the height of the headerHeight variable. As mentioned above this works perfectly on Chrome for desktop but it's scrolling without the offset in the mobile version.

Thanks in advance.

Edit 2: The problem in this instance comes from the callback to change focus after the scroll animation. The page scrolls and then jumps to the focused element, ignoring the header offset. The only problem now is if I remove the focus callback then the page becomes inaccessible for screen readers etc.

Comment: Please go read [ask], and how to create a [mcve]. Without seeing your HTML (& CSS, as far as relevant) that this script code gets applied to, it is impossible to say where you are going wrong. Also, please describe what you have done so far to debug this. Have you checked which values your script is working with, either by interactively debugging it, or at least making debug outputs using console.log ...?

Comment: Updated question to a link to the full page, I'm not sure how I would go about outputting the scroll location in this instance? I'm currently logging the headerHeight value when the function is executed and this is showing the correct value as the viewport is changed.

Comment: It's particularly frustrating to debug as I can only replicate the issue on my phone where I don't have access to dev tools.

Comment: For example Chrome dev tools in device mode with an iPhone 7 selected seems to reproduce the problem fine, so you should be able to debug it in that environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is caused by the callback function where the target is focused again. It's a bit of a dirty fix but it appears adding a margin to :focus on the affected areas corrects the problem:

```css
#projects:focus {
  margin-top:80px;
}

@media all and (min-width:600px) {
  #projects:focus {
    margin-top:0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Test on your animate function to set a setTimeout to 200ms.

Your function animate is executed before the DOM and plugin JS (like slider or other) is fully executed.